# Hide warning messages in console window

Tags: google-chrome

The Chrome console window is full of warning messages that I like to hide.
Is it possible to hide the warning logs?
I only want to show my custom logs e.g. console.log('mymessage');

This is how the console windowbar looks like:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just using `console.error`, and changing the level of your log to `error`? At least in Chrome, I don't see any way you can hide specific console messages, unless you change the "Level" of the console. Of course, it's not good practice to do this, but if it's just for testing, and you absolutely need the other messages to be hidden, may be worth a shot.

Comment: Oh. Based off of that edit, then, you may want to use Edge for testing, since you can switch errors and warnings off (as per my answer)

Comment: Any idea why the console bar has changed in Chrome. The older one is much better.

Comment: I guess possibly because the new bar is more consistent with how logging's usually set up? Usually you set a verbosity level, and everything at or above that level is displayed

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just recently there was a Chrome update. Now filtering single message types is possible (Verbose, Info, Warnings, Errors)! (My Version: Version 60.0.3112.90)

When opening the console, instead of selecting a "filter level", you can now check or uncheck each message type.

[image: Screenshot of Console in Chrome]

Answer (score 13):

As of Chrome version 78 (Dec 2019), in the "Console" tab, click on the "Default levels" pulldown, and uncheck the types of messages you don't want displayed.
[image]

Comment: Filter sidebar must be closed. (it overrides defaults)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

At the top bar of the console log you can select what kind of messages should be shown.

**All** is selected by default. Select **error** to see only error.

You can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> to select multiple message types.

Comment: Strange, this is how the console window looked like before. But see my updated question the console window looks differently with a dropdown. And I am missing the Logs filter tag :s

Answer (score 1):

First off: you can hide all warnings and show only `console.log` output if you are using Microsoft Edge. In the console, there are a couple of icons representing the different levels of log output you may be using - error, warning, and info. If you just want to hide warnings, you can simply toggle the warning icon to off.

Also, if you are on firefox, you can set the log to only display info, in which case the warnings will also be hidden.

Next, to elaborate on the other answer, and phrase what I said (above in my comment) in the form of an answer:

For chrome, you cannot toggle specific levels off individually (newer versions of Chrome). Instead, you have to set an overall verbosity level for the log. By using the strictest level (i.e. the level that displays the least), you can minimize console messages that are created by portions of code that you did not write. In this case, that is the `error` level.

If you are just trying to hide warning messages for testing purposes, you can, for the time being, switch over to only logging messages at the `error` level. In production, this is **not** good practice, as it doesn't let you differentiate between helpful info log messages or actual errors.

To log a message as an error, use:

```
console.error('mymessage');
```

Then, as mentioned above, you can change the Level of your console output to error, which will only show you error messages. It will ignore `console.log` as well as any warning messages.

Be sure to change your calls to `console.error` back to `console.log` when you are done with the development phase of your work, for any instances where you are calling `console.error` with some message that does not describe an error.

Now, if you are getting warnings due to something you are doing in your code, you may want to consider spending time trying to correct whatever is causing those warnings to appear. Warnings are generally well thought out, and are there to help you prevent issues in your code that you may not be aware of. Correcting any issues in your code would also cause the warning messages to go away.

**NOTE:** you cannot tell the console to only display messages you print out, even at the level of verbosity you set your console to. This is because the console would have no way of knowing which statements you are logging out, versus which statements code your webpage is running that was written by someone else is logging out. The steps mentioned in this answer as well as the other are *workarounds* that may improve your situation.

**UPDATE:** It seems like Chrome has reintroduced the ability to enable/disable different levels of console logging individually. Now, when clicking on log level, you can toggle whether certain log levels are enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Under the console tab it is now possible to highlight the message type as a general filter.  There is also a filter box right next to the eyeball.  So if you put a unique flag in your console.log then it will show only your messages with this flag.

But in general.  I think you want to click the 'Info' item as highlighted below to just obtain the console.log messages
[image: screenshot showing console 'info' selection]

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to select multiple types (e.g. user messages& warnings).  Chrome has an awful lot of 'warnings' these days that things like adwords throw so the console can be pretty cluttered

Answer (score 0):

There is a drop down next to filter, where can you select only things you require.

**Note** : ReactJS warnings are actually displayed in red as errors. So to remove them you need to uncheck errors too.

[image]